# Teensy (Arduino-like development board) 5V and 3.3V supplies

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, arduino, voltage-regulator, teensy

I am using a [Teensy 4.0 microcontroller](https://www.pjrc.com/store/teensy40.html) for a project.
For the project, there are lots of peripheral ICs in the design that allow for general purpose I/O, such as multiplexers, ADCs, and waveform generators. The components can all work from either of the 5V or 3.3V pins of the microcontroller. My question is, when should a component work from one pin or the other?

I understand that using lower voltages uses less power, but if that is not a concern for this early iteration of the design (this is admittedly bad practice), so why would I choose one over the other?
During these initial design steps, I am unsure of the exact current usage, so I avoid the 3.3V pin for more critical components. A voltage regulator reduces the 5V VIN to 3.3V which has a maximum output current of 250mA, so is it good practice to avoid many connections to this pin for bigger projects?

Comment: If you already know where you are headed then you should probably do the same thing, early. The reason is that this, right now, is an "unknown." You don't know if you will run into troubles, later. A good rule is to pull to the front of your work, all unknowns, and then solve each one ***before*** you get too deep into the stuff you already feel prepared for. Turning unknowns into knowns should be step 1.

Comment: I don't mean take on the entire project early. I mean you should design an experiment that narrowly focuses upon the 3.3 V and 5 V interface questions you have. This means first listing all the ways these interfaces are likely to be used, later. Then design an experiment to test each until you know exactly how to solve each one, precisely and well. Document each result and your conclusions. Then set that aside as "known". At that point, you can certainly just run everything 5 V or 3.3 V for other testing, because you already have your answers when things change.

Comment: Terminology technicality: a Teensy is not a microcontroller - it is a development board which *contains* a microcontroller (the NXP i.MX RT1062).

Comment: Thanks for the comments and responses. The testing process that @periblepsis proposed has been helpful in redesigning some aspect of the circuit. I have switched most components to work off of the 3.3V to use less power except the ADC so that I can measure a larger range of voltages.

Answer (score 5):

The MCU chip itself operates with 3.3V I/O (except the USB PHY) so signals would best be 3.3V. Neither analog nor digital pins are 5V tolerant.

If you have some required peripheral that needs 5V and has 5V I/O you would have to add voltage translators.

You may or may not be able to power external 3.3V devices external to the module from the built-in regulator. If the current draw or other requirements prohibit it, you can add an external LDO.

Comment: The important thing is to first look at what the 5V and 3.3V lines actually represent, and- in the general case- what happens to the "5V" line if the development board is powered not from USB but from a 6V battery pack via a barrel connector.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of posts telling you many different and contradictory ways of doing this. The bible for this is at  https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/electronics/power-pins There are the real parts and the clones and the so called boards, they are not all the same. The information is for the real boards they manufacturer, not other copies as they have no control over them. I keep my loads to less than 50 mA for testing etc, I never use the 3V3. Never ever connect a motor to an Arduino it will destroy the Arduino. When I build a project I use an external power supply, keeping the Arduino cool helps it do its job without complaints.  I also use Vin as the board will give me some extra filtering. Some boards are not protected for reverse polarity on Vin, the ones I have are. Reverse polarity on the 5V and 3V3 and it is gone. To my knowledge none of the boards protect for that.

I do not like level translators so I pick the peripherals that operate at the same voltage as the micro. This will require less wires and the layout will be much simpler without translators.